# Trying to duplicate items within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to duplicate the items within the array. I am using this function but it keeps returning this error when i try to run it.

[4, "Ulysses", 42, "false"]

```
function doubleTrouble(array){
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    array.splice(i, 0, array[i]);
}
}
```

Error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[5700:000002D91C63EFF0]     6774 ms: Scavenge 1617.8 (1635.3) -> 1602.0 (1635.3) MB, 0.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.937, current mu = 0.936) allocation failure 
[5700:000002D91C63EFF0]     6794 ms: Scavenge 1617.8 (1635.3) -> 1602.0 (1635.3) MB, 0.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.937, current mu = 0.936) allocation failure 
[5700:000002D91C63EFF0]     6818 ms: Scavenge 1617.8 (1635.3) -> 1602.0 (1635.3) MB, 0.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.937, current mu = 0.936) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF78E5606CF v8::internal::Isolate::ArchiveSpacePerThread+4607
 2: 00007FF78E4F4AA6 SSL_get_quiet_shutdown+65190
 3: 00007FF78E4F59A6 node::OnFatalError+294
 4: 00007FF78EDF843E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF78EDDCB0D v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF78EC75B3C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1468
 7: 00007FF78E9B9B8C v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+4348
 8: 00007FF78EE7F74D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+456749
 9: 00007FF78EEA6DAC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+618124
10: 00000217DFBC4127
```

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+splice+in+for+loop+infinite) of [Looping through array using splice method infinite loop javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48362415/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

You have a changing length of the array because of adding an item at every loop to it.

To overcome this, you could ierate from the end and add the doubled item until you reach index zero.

```js
function doubleTrouble(array) {
    let i = array.length;
   
    while (i--) array.splice(i, 0, array[i]);
}

const array = [4, "Ulysses", 42, "false"];

doubleTrouble(array);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks this actually occurred to me this morning. Just overlooked it I guess.